# Shorthand for lens chaining with _Just

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a data object which I access as follows.

```hs
foo ^? lens1 . _Just . lens2 . _Just . lens3 . _Just
```

Is there some builtin lens operator that allows this to be shorthanded like bellow?

```hs
foo ^? lens1 © lens2 © lens3
```

Comment: Perhaps it is more useful to explain what you aim to do?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem shorthand the notation of `foo ^? lens1 . _Just . lens2 . _Just . lens3 . _Just` to something like `foo ^? lens1 © lens2 © lens3` with one of the operators from Lens operators.

Comment: I am building from the top of my head, but doesn't `foo ^? lens1 .  lens2 . lens3 . _Just` work?

Comment: Is `foo ^? j lens1 . j lens2 . j lens3` good enough? If so, you could just define `j lens = lens . _Just`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I know, thx, question was mostly if something similar exist in lens library already

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not in lens but you can easily define your own operator to insert `_Just` in between two optics:

```
infixl 9 .?.
(.?.) :: Traversal' s (Maybe t) -> Traversal' t u -> Traversal' s u
s .?. t = s . _Just . t
```

where `Traversal'` is the smallest common supertype of `Lens'` and `Prism'` expressible in lens (there is a more precise variant with profunctor lenses). Or here is a more general signature:

```
(.?.) :: (Choice p, Applicative f) => Optic' p f s (Maybe t) -> Optic' p f t u -> Optic' p f s u
```

Note that `(.?.)` only inserts `_Just` in the middle; you still have to append it at the end:

```
foo ^? lens1 .?. lens2 .?. lens3 . _Just
```